# Preguntas con posibles fallas de seguridad en su código

Tags: discusión

No soy un experto en seguridad, pero como programadores responsables siempre debemos minimizar los posibles fallos de seguridad que puedan tener nuestras aplicaciones, teniendo en cuenta esto y que stackoverflow es un lugar al que acuden muchas personas que están aprendiendo y que su "instinto" llama a hacer 'copy & paste' al código que vemos en preguntas o respuestas (Yo lo hice más de una vez). Mi pregunta es:

¿Qué se debe hacer al respecto de preguntas que tienen posibles fallos de seguridad?

¿Las respondemos, pero en la respuesta recomendamos que puede tener una falla de seguridad?

¿Dejamos un comentario y las ignoramos?

Con todos los descubrimientos de fallos en seguridad que se han venido dando siento que seriamos complices si nada mas respondemos la pregunta

---

**Edición**

Se puede encontrar un poco mas al respecto en esta [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2636/estoy-obligado-a-avisar-de-un-problema-a-un-usuario-que-est%c3%a1-preguntando-por), gracias por el comentario @A.Cedano.

Comment: Si alguien copia código de una pregunta está jugando con fuego: la pregunta suele tener errores, por eso es una pregunta. Y las respuestas hay que, sobre todo, entenderlas antes de copiarlas. Pero si vemos un problema en una pregunta que es ajeno a lo que se intenta resolver, nunca está de más avisar del mismo.

Comment: Yo personalmente si detecto algún problema de seguridad, bien sea en la pregunta o en la respuesta, le comento al usuario cual puede ser el problema y si es relevante algún enlace. Es un caso muy típico el código vulnerable a SQL Injection.

Comment: @PabloLozano conozco personas a nivel profesional que no miran la descripción de la respuesta, solo copian y pegan, de ahí viene mi duda de que tan socialemente responsables somos al responder tales preguntas, tal ves se debería poner una nota al principio de la respuesta o algo que llame mucho la atención sobre el posible fallo de seguridad de la respuesta

Comment: En la pregunta siguiente: **[¿Estoy “obligado” a avisar de un problema a un usuario que está preguntando por un problema distinto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2636/29967)** se abordó más o menos la misma situación.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano busqué en la red a ver si encontraba algo pero no se me ocurrieron esas palabras en mi busqueda, agregaré tu comentario a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal, sería responder y aconsejar que revise el código por sus posibles vulnerabilidades.

Por muy experto que puedas ser a la hora de programar, todos somos humanos y podemos olvidarnos de cosas, ademas esto de la programación es una aprendizaje constante, en el que cada día, por mucho que sepas, siempre puedes aprender algo nuevo de otro compañero

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo contigo pero muchas veces los comentarios o incluso las descripciones de las respuestas son ignoradas por algunos programadores, ¿Como se podría resaltar el posible fallo de seguridad que tiene el código? Ya sea en la respuesta o en la pregunta en si

Comment: Siempre queda el resaltado de alguna manera, bien sea poniendo en negrita el aviso de la seguridad o bien resaltarlo en amarillo en la respuesta.